# Need help dismantling these claims!

Tags: hadith-interpretation, malaikah, doubts

This is a copy paste of the article I had come across.

The story follows prior to the events of Banu Qurayzah. From this examination, we find that the first perpetrators of the attack was instigated firstly by Muhammad and his companion Dihya al-Kalbi.

However, we find that according to https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3721, that during the siege of Medina, in the Battle of Trench, there were rumours that the Banu Qurayzah planned to betray the Muslims by attacking them with the help of the Meccans. Nevertheless, those rumours proved wrong and neither did the Banu Qurayzah help the Meccans, nor did they kill or even injure a single Muslim. The Muslims were freely coming in and out of the area of Banu Qurayzah during that siege, which continued for one month. There was no trench present where the Banu Qurayzah resided, but they didn't allow Meccans to enter their area and attack Muslims from the backside.

According to https://sunnah.com/bukhari/56, we find that the when the Meccans eventually lifted the siege and returned to Mecca, the Muslims also put down their weapons and engaged in bathing. At that point, neither the Muslims blamed Banu Qurayzah for any betrayal nor did they rush to attack them.

Muhammad also laid down his weapons, like other Muslims, and he was also taking a bath at Umm Salama's (one of his wives) house, Dihyah came to him and suggested that they should attack the Banu Qurayza, accusing them of treachery, and seize their women, children, and wealth.

Although Muhammad agreed with Dihyah al-Kalbi's suggestion, he still needed a pretext to carry out the attack. Thus, Muhammad once again claimed to receive a revelation, stating that Gabriel appeared to him in the form of Dihya, commanding the Muslims to immediately attack Banu Qurayzah.

Ibn Kathir described the details of the Battle of the Trench and the subsequent attack on the Banu Qurayza tribe in the commentary of verse 33:26 https://www.alim.org/quran/read-surah/33?taf=26:

> When Allah helped him (i.e. Muhammad) by suppressing his enemy and driving them back disappointed and lost (in the battle of the Trench), having gained nothing, the Messenger of Allah returned to Al-Madinah in triumph and the people put down their weapons. While the Messenger of Allah was washing off the dust of battle in the house of Umm Salamah, may Allah be pleased with her, Jibril (i.e. Gabriel), upon him be peace, came to him wearing a turban of brocade, riding on a mule on which was a cloth of silk brocade. He said, "Have you put down your weapons, O Messenger of Allah'' He said, "Yes.'' He said, "But the angels have not put down their weapons. I have just now come back from pursuing the people.'' Then he said: "Allah, may He be blessed and exalted, commands you to get up and go to Banu Qurayzah.'' According to another report, "What a fighter you are! Have you put down your weapons'' He said, "Yes.'' He said, "But we have not put down our weapons yet, get up and go to these people.'' He said: "Where'' He said, "Banu Qurayzah, for Allah has commanded me to shake them.'' So the Messenger of Allah got up immediately, and commanded the people to march towards Banu Qurayzah, who were a few miles from Al-Madinah. This was after Salat Az-Zuhr. He said, (No one among you should pray `Asr except at Banu Qurayzah.) So, the people set out, and the time for the prayer came while they were still on the road. Some of them prayed on the road, saying, "The Messenger of Allah only wanted to make us march quickly.'' Others said, "We will not pray it until we reach Banu Qurayzah.''

However, a large problem we find is that the person whom Muhammad called Jibril, people had seen him leaving the house of Umm Salamah, and it was Dihyah al-Kalbi. Upon that, Muhammad claimed that Gabriel came to him in the form of Dihyah al-Kalbi.

Ibn Kathir further writes under verse 33:26 https://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=1&tTafsirNo=7&tSoraNo=33&tAyahNo=26&tDisplay=yes&Page=3&Size=1&LanguageId=1:

> Suddenly, Jibril (Gabriel) came to Muhammad and there was dust on his clothes. He asked, "Why have you put down your weapons, while the angels have not put down their weapons yet. Stand up and go out to the Banu Qurayza and fight against them." Then the Messenger of Allah wore his armor and ordered people to depart towards Banu Qurayzah. He passed by the houses of the tribe of Banu Tamim, who were living in the neighbourhood of the mosque of Muhammad (where the house of Umm Salama was situated), and asked, "Who passed by you?" They replied, "Dhahyah Al-Kalbi passed by us." Dhahyah Al-Kalbi resembled Jibril in his beard, teeth, and face.

Likewise, according to https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4980, Umm Salama had felt confused over the incident as well. Claiming that she has seen Dihya al-Kalbi. A question arises, why why didn't Muhammad immediately refute her and told that it was not Dihyah al-Kalbi but Gabriel in the form of him?

According to https://web.archive.org/web/20230609054258/https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&flag=1&bk_no=58&ID=1155

The apostle passed by a number of his companions in al-Saurayn before he got to Banu Qurayza and asked if anyone had passed them. They replied that Dihy al-Kalbi had passed upon a white mule with a saddle covered with a piece of brocade. He said, 'That was Gabriel who has been sent to B. Qurayza to shake their castles and strike terror to their hearts.'

Now, after further assessing the evidence, it's apparent that Umm Salamah or the people of Banu Tamim also found that it was not Gabriel but Dihyah al-Kalbi, then the next excuse is ready that Gabriel appeared in the form of Dihyah al-Kalbi.

I'd like to ask the readers of this article to contemplate the following:

- Why did Gabriel not manifest himself to Muhammad in his usual unseen form?
- What purpose did it serve for Gabriel to appear in the form of a human?
- Instead of providing any advantage, it only resulted in confusion among people.

Likewise, please consider the following in accordance to https://sunnah.com/muslim:1767a. After the event with Banu Qurayza, Muhammad, without any excuse or pretext this time, expelled the remaining small Jewish tribes from Medina. They were expelled from Medina without any valid reason, even though they had not committed any claimed treachery. They were not just expelled from the city; when Muslims gained more power, Muhammad issued a new order to expel all Jews and Christians from the entire Arabian Peninsula.

Need someone to make a proper rebuttal to these claims.